# How do I include plurals but exclude singulars?

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP/MySQL - include plurals but exclude singulars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637254/php-mysql-include-plurals-but-exclude-singulars)

I am building a site with a requirement to include plural words but exclude singlular words, as well as include longer phrases but exclude shorter phrases found within it.

For example:

- a search for "Read" should return results with 'read' within it, but not 'bread' or 'breads'.
- a search for "book" should return results with 'book' within it, but not 'paperback book' or 'hardback book'.

The query I have tried is:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (field LIKE '%read%') AND (field NOT LIKE '%bread%' OR field NOT LIKE '%breads%')
```

...which clearly returned no results, even though there are records with 'read', 'bread' and 'breads' in it.

I understand why this query is failing (I'm telling it to both include and exclude the same strings) but I cannot think of the correct logic to apply to the code to get it working.

To clarify...

- The fields will be from a select list, not a text input, so the phrases going through are strictly controlled - the user cannot enter their own free text.
- Speed of results/server load is not necessarily an issue here as it will be a closed, internal system.

Comment: You've posted this question already. Don't create duplicates.